# How to complete this proof of the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $X$ a set, and $*$ and action of $G$ on $X.$ Let $x \in X$ and denote by $\operatorname{Orb} \left( x \right)$ the orbit of $x$ and by $\operatorname{Stab} \left( x \right)$ the stabilizer of $x$ by $G.$ I have to prove that $\left| \operatorname{Stab} \left( x \right) \right| \cdot \left| \operatorname{Orb} \left( x \right) \right| = \left| G \right|,$ for every $x \in X.$

First I prove that, for every $b \in G,$ there is exactly $\left| \operatorname{Stab} \left( x \right) \right|$ elements $a$ of the form $a = b c$ where $c \in \operatorname{Stab} \left( x \right)$ such that $* \left( a, x \right) = * \left( b, x \right).$

Then I show that $\operatorname{Orb} \left( x \right)$ has exactly $\left| \operatorname{Stab} \left( x \right) \right|$ elements $y$ such that $* \left( a, y \right) = * \left( b, y \right).$

However I don't know how to conclude for this that $\left| \operatorname{Stab} \left( x \right) \right| \cdot \left| \operatorname{Orb} \left( x \right) \right| = \left| G \right|.$

Can someone help me with what I am missing?

Comment: In fact ${\rm Orb}(x)\cong G/{\rm Stab}(x)$ are isomorphic as $G$-sets.

Answer (score 0):

Set $x\in X$ then  :

$$G=\bigcup_{y\in O(x)}\{g\in G| g.x=y\} $$

Then the union is disjoint hence you have :

$$|G|=\sum_{y\in O(x)}|\{g\in G| g.x=y\}| $$

now by your first statement (First I prove that...) show that :

$$|\{g\in G| g.x=y\}|=|Stab(x)|$$

hence :

$$|G|=\sum_{y\in O(x)}|Stab(x)| $$

Now the summand does not depend on the internal variable of the sum so :

$$|G|=|\{y\in O(x)\}||Stab(x)|=|O(x)||Stab(x)| $$

I am not very sure about your second statement so I did not use it, anyway to do this you just have to write $G$ as a disjoint union of those sets which have all the same cardinal...